# How to let maven project work locally by intelij-idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We have a maven project works fine in a internet enabled environment, now we need make it work in a local environment by IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition .

we have try following actions:

1. in setting->build->maven:
   check the box "work offline"
2. download all needed jars into a local folder
3. in settings.xml set local Repository, such as

*C:\FCA\Repository*

4.build the project, it seems that some packages can be find in pom.xml(no error message in pom.xml), but can't be find in java code , and build failed. You can refer to attached picture for details

How can we get it done locally? thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Please check that dependencies are added to classpath in "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies"

Comment: Thank you, in this ways, the import statement is ok for some package, such as Lombok.data , but some method of the class can not be found,  I can not access plugin market to add it, so I add the jar as you mentioned, and add the plugin description in pom.xml(as other answers for this problem in stack overflow), still not work

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: This strange issue may related with our security policy, your solution works fine for a pc without strict policy, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Under "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven" you can find options:

- Maven home directory
- User settings file
- Local repository

There you have to provide path to your local maven installation (by default IntelliJ has it's own Maven provided). It should automatically read your settings.xml file and set local repository. If not please also provide those two and it will work fine with your local libs.

Comment: Thank you, I have set them, pom.xml should have error message if I set them wrong, I wonder if the pom.xml and java code search jars differently?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that question. Maven uses pom.xml to configure your project and find dependencies that you need. Every dependency is then included as external library to your project, which you can later use in your java code.

Comment: This strange issue may related with our security policy, your solution works  fine for a pc without strict policy, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, run `mvn dependency:go-offline`. Then you can build in offline mode as long as you don't change any of the dependencies.

If you do this to work inside a company with several developers, think about setting up a Nexus/Artifactory for you company.

Comment: Thank you, I just find I don't have permission to run 'cmd' (I'm frustrated), windows power shell can't run this command successfully,  can I do it by IDE?

Comment: I find it strange that you cannot run a cmd. You should also be able to run this command on powershell. From eclipse, you can use `Run as -> Maven build ...`, but I don't know IntelliJ.

Comment: This is a policy issue, our policy very strict for some tasks, thank you.